# what's the simplest way to have a local mail server for demonstration purpose?

Tags: email, demo

I'm building a demo computer for presentation. The demos require to send / receive emails for some demo users (3 or 4).

What is the simplest, free way, to have a local mail server (pop or imap and smtp) ?

As it's a demo computer, I don't care about security, performance, advanced features, etc.
The only requirement is that the solution must be light as I'll run a lots of apps on the single computer.

FYI, the demo computer won't have internet connection, and is running Windows 2008 R2 x64.
The target client is Outlook 2010 X64.

Comment: You want to send emails to ? yourself? because you said there is no internet... If you install Windows Server with Exchange then it will work.. or you can use ubuntu with postfix too..

Comment: send email locally from user1 to user2, for **demonstration** purpose. Do you really think Exchange is a **light** solution ?

Comment: Yea- because when you isntall Windows Server with Exchange.. It is there out of the box no messing around. Setting up other users is easy as pie.. because the exhange sets up the other users on other domain users.. in 1 click.. user1 sent to user2 .. isntant. Installing 3rd party.. you will spend half your life configuring smtp/pop accounts.. ontop of a server

Comment: exchange is not out of the box with windows server... and it's so heavy I'll need to have a separate server to run it. Lastly, I don't need 3000 users... only 3 or 4. it's for **demonstration** purpose, as I said.

Comment: http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html

Comment: Yea sorry- i was thinking of server2003 with exchange..   or this ? http://www.hmailserver.com/

Comment: If you wanted a complete mailserver setup which would be easy and fairly *light* (depends on your host PC) then postfix running off a VM would totally isolate the mailserver from anything else - it would even have a seperate IP... It's also free! :)

Comment: as the computer have 4GB of ram, and as it will run sharepoint 2010, Visual Studio 2010, Office 2010 simultaneously, I can't afford virtualizing a separate OS

Comment: Doesn't take much resources to run postfix, i've happily run it on a P2-550 with 64mb RAM before now... Or that could've been sendmail...

Comment: LOL @ the Exchange idea.  "I've bought with me this Boeing 747 to teach the class how an airplane wing works"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [MDaemon](http://www.altn.com/Products/Free-Windows-Mail-Server/).
A google search shows a lot of other free Windows compatible mail servers too.

Comment: yep, MDaemon looks like this is what I need

Answer (score 2):

i also found hmail to be a nice solution, it also allows you to authenticate directly against active directory which is a nice side effect in a windows domain

http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=welcome

Comment: I'll take a look at this product. AD authentication should actually simplify the whole thing